# Searching a column value by other column in sqlite android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I would like to search a column value by other column searching.

For example:
There are 3 columns a, b, c. I am going to get the value of column c by searching column b.

How can I do that?

Do I need to use `cursor`?

```
public String getc(String code) 
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_OWNER, new String[] { a , b , c }, b + "=?", new String[] { code }, null, null, null, null);

}
```

So, where should I put the select c?

Comment: Run a query like this: "SELECT c FROM MyTable WHERE b = SomeValue". Of course, you need a cursor. If b is a TEXT column, SomeValue must be surrounded by apostrophes ('SomeValue')

Comment: public String getc(String code) { SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_OWNER, new String[] { a , b , c }, b + "=?", new String[] { code }, null, null, null, null);
}   where should I put the select c?

Thanks.

Comment: **Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT c FROM MyTable WHERE b = ?", new String[] {code});**

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this

```
String [] valueyouwishtosearchfor = {"somevalue"};  // or get this however you like
Cursor query = cr.query(TABLE_OWNER, new String[] { c }, " where b=?",
            valueyouwishtosearchfor, null);
```

Comment: I have tried to use this query, but there is an error about "
        String CREATE_OWNER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_OWNER + "(" + KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_CODE + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_NUMBER + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_SUM + "TEXT NOT NULL  );";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_OWNER_TABLE);". There is a problem near where too. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This isn't a query, a query starts with a SELECT statement.  The first thing I see with this create statement the initial key to the table.  SQLite wants _id as the first key column, as follows:   private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
    + TABLE_OWNER + " (" + KEY_NAME
    + " integer primary key autoincrement, ... and KEY_NAME should be valued as "_id", after that you can add any columns you want as foreign keys.